# Changing font style in Google Colab Markdown text

Tags: html, markdown, google-colaboratory

is this possible to change the markdown's font style in Colab?
I wrote this CSS code but as it doesn't work, I don't know how to use it (or if it's possible or not).
The code perfectly works in a `html` file but not working on Colab:

```markdown
<html>
<head>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Alike+Angular&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <style>
        p {
            font-family: 'Alike Angular', serif;
            font-size: 22px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
</html>

<span>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,</p>
</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Two problems:

1. That is the URL of the Github page *about* the TrueType file, not the TrueType file itself. You need to add `?raw=true`:

   https://github.com/cyrealtype/Alike/blob/master/Alike-Regular.ttf?raw=true
2. The server, that serves the TrueType file, needs to [give you its permission](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) for you to include it. And it's unlikely Github will give you that permission, because it's not a file delivery service.

You need to either download the font file and serve it from the same web server where you host your HTML/CSS files, or find a font provider that serves it from a server that gives you permission, for example, Google Fonts, which has "Alike": https://fonts.google.com/?query=alike

Comment: thanks, I've first tried to use Google Fonts font delivery service but I didn't know how to use files like `.ttf` from here & still don't know how to use it inside the code. where can I access the HTML code after selecting the font? tried your given URL & this too: `https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Alike`, not working.

Comment: That isn't the URL to the font, its the URL to Googles list of fonts. Go to it in your browser, click the font, click on the link "select this style" and then you get a side bar with the source code to use.

Comment: thanks, unfortunately, looks like the Colab doesn't support custom font, edited my question & added a code that works in an HTML file but not on Colab.