# How Do You Change the Font Style in Colab Markdown?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, markdown, google-colaboratory

What code is needed in Google Colab to change the Markdown font style from its default? E.g., I would like to change it to Times New Roman.

In Jupyter Notebook, the following code works:

```
## <span style='font-family:Times New Roman'> Hello World </span>
```

However, this code does not work when I try it in Google Colab, but instead creates the text with the default Colab Markdown font style.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Maybe you can refer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71378626/changing-font-style-in-google-colab-markdown-text).

Answer (score 5):

The only way I've found to change font on Colab is to change the attribute "face" of the tag "font". For example:

```html
<font face="Rage" size=7 color='#d39aed'> Hello <font>
```

(note that the font face attribute is not supported by HTML5).
Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

This does not fully answer your question because it does not use markdown but basically does what you want in your example:

you can use the HTML module from IPython.display and run html as code in your cell

```
from IPython.display import HTML
HTML("<h2><span style='font-family:Times New Roman'> Hello World </span></h2>")
```

output:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm not very familiar with the Colab system but most markdowns doesn't support changing the font family. I would recommend using a form of HTML page that supports CSS to change the font.

Hope that helps!

~ Ryan

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).